# What would be considered an “emerging tech” in Star Wars?

Tags: technological-development

I'm trying to think of something in Star Wars that might be researched by the time of the end of the Skywalker Saga.
I was told on another site that technology only gets refined or bigger/smaller in Star Wars; but I refuse to believe it. I believe what Stiegler said. Technology never stops advancing. I've been playing with a lot of ideas but none fits in my mind for Star Wars. Teleportation, time travel and matter replication seem like the obvious next steps for technology but I feel that those techs would be too much of a game changer. Teleportation would eliminate space travel, time travel would be EXTREMELY dangerous if it fell into the wrong hands and matter replicators would make Star Wars a post-scarcity society which I DON'T want.

The obvious answer seems to be nanotech or tech that goes even smaller like Picotech or Femtotech. Yet nanotech is emerging in the world (late 2019) and I'm sure that Star Wars has nanotech everywhere; so much so that it doesn't even faze people anymore. The absence of teleportation, time travel and matter replication leads me to conclude that they simply cannot be done by their laws of science since all 3 are things all intelligent life forms would think to want to create. I myself also feel anything smaller than nano is impossible so that rules out pico and femto Tech.

I'm getting ready to give up and except their are only so many ideas that people can come up with and perhaps I exhausted them all. UNLESS......

Does anybody have an idea for an emerging tech in the Star Wars world that isn't time travel, teleportation, matter replication or pico/femtotech?

Comment: Spacegoing Banthas, opening the whole galaxy for the Tusken Raiders to maraud through. Really, the Star Wars universe *looks* cool, but it doesn't actually make much sense. That's why new space-operas are so easy to handwave into the existing quilt.

Comment: Perhaps this should be moved to https://scifi.stackexchange.com?

Comment: No. I asked something similar on Sci fi stack exchange and they closed it.

Comment: Detonating nukes in a planet's Van Allen belt. Let's show those clankers who is wearing the trousers!

Comment: Real talk. There is no "emerging" in SW. There actually is legit nanotech, see the Umbara arc, and it does faze the clones. There are zombies, several variants, lasersword-resistant kaijus, and BIG EMP. I guess the only emergin tech would be the one that was already invented but fell out of fashion and is now starting to rise again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not relate to Worldbuilding

Comment: Ahh. My first vote to close

Answer (score 2):

**Bioengineering**

The Star Wars universe is filled with metal structures, vehicles, and technology. One of the few types of tech it is lacking is the usage of “custom” living things or life in general. This is shown in the New Jedi Order books(which are no longer considered canon), in which the invading Yuuzhan Vong use bioengineered ships. These ships and their living weapons are completely unfamiliar to the well-informed main characters. There was nothing introduced in the new canon that would change this unfamiliarity. Any ships created from living things would be completely new to the inhabitants of the Star Wars galaxy.

Answer (score 0):

## Bigger Faster Better

### Bigger

Return of the Jedi's death star was several times larger than a New Hopes and by the Force Awakens whole planets are being moved.

### Faster

It still takes appreciable time to travel from place to place.  The Millennium Falcon is 40 years old at this point, based on a design that's 80.  There has to be something that can do the Kessel Run in less time, or distance, or whatever...

### Better

In a some ways we have better medical technology now than the Star Wars universe.  They are also lacking in the entertainment technology.

Answer (score 0):

**Forcetech.**

To use the force you have to subscribe to hokey religions and use ancient weapons.  Then you can do some cool stuff, like choke people from a distance but you need mental discipline and all that jazz.  Being a master of the force is sort of like being an excellent archer - you can do some amazing things with those arrows because you have practiced for decades and were born with gifts.

If I get to fighting, I want to do amazing things with projectiles too, with no practice, no inborn gifts (at all) and also tripping on shrooms.  Like with a machine gun.  Forcetech is the machine gun equivalent for the force, and arrows.  Am I straining the metaphor?  In any case: Midi-chlorian manipulator tech will let me choke many folks at once, from great distances, and give them wedgies and draw mustaches on their faces just like I was the sithiest of Siths.  And I am not all deformed either like Siths; nay - I remain super hot.  Like a Jedi maestro I can project a convincing Force replica of myself at a great distance to distract a ATAT battalion, but my replica doesnt just stand there - it also kicks ass, and I don't die when I am done; on the contrary I feel great and also feel great affection for my Force replica who I think is also digging me.  In a fraternal way, I mean!

It is obvious where this is going, and the awesomeness of that place.  Force tech.  Everyone can use the force.  Sweet force tech.

Comment: If we consider the saga "Knights of the Old Republic" canon, this has been done before. The rakata race did it and didn't end well. But that's another story. In SW the force is vage descrived. Midiclorians aren´t all you need to control the force.  Returning to the Rakata empire. They used the force and explored their limits. They had force-devices and stuff. But they didn't develop any device that allows a non force user to use the force (they can't use the force any more, that's why i'm sure they didn't develop any device thath allows them to after their fall).

Comment: However they did had devices that helped them to power up their force powers. It seems that you can't have a device that use force that can be used by a non force user. For example: Sith holocron and Jedi holocron can only be open with the force.

Comment: @MiguelNoTeimporta  What I want is powers without practice, luck or discipline.  The dream we all dream of.  I would be ok with just moving things from a distance to my hand, like a beer.  Moving the fridge open first too.

Comment: “To live life, you need problems. If you get what you want the minute you want it, then what's the point of living?” ― Jake the Dog.